# Robo Copy /XF invalid?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, robocopy

Why am I getting an Invalid Parameter error on the /XF line?

```
ERROR : Invalid Job File, Line #4 :"/XF *.avi *.mov *.mp4 *.mv4 *.ai"
```

I don't have any stray characters on the line. Must be something dumb....

H: is a Windows Server 2012 file share, P: is an external USB drive, OS is Windows 7

Commands are OK w/o the /XF line.

```
/SD:H:
/DD:P:\H

/XF *.avi *.mov *.mp4 *.mv4 *.ai 

/E  :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
/PURGE  :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.

/XO ::Excludes Older files. - keeps files newer on the destination

/V  ::Produces verbose output (including skipped files).
::/L    ::Lists files without copying, deleting, or applying a time stamp to any files.

/LOG+:roboSlowH.log ::Redirects output to the specified file, overwriting the file if it already exists (LOG+ appends)
::/FP   :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
/NDL    ::Turns off logging of directory names. Full file pathnames (as opposed to simple file names) will be shown if /NDL is used.
/NP     ::Turns off copy progress indicator (% copied).


/R:0    ::Specifies the number of retries on failed copies. (The default is 1 million.)
/W:0    ::Specifies the wait time between retries. (The default is 30 seconds.)

/IPG:90 : Inter-Packet Gap (ms), to free bandwidth on slow lines
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've edited the Job file incorrectly for that option.

The proper/offical way to make a job file is to lay out your Robocopy command and then add `/save:JobFileName` to the end.  This will save it to a proper RCJ job file.

After doing that, and viewing the resulting file in a text editor, it becomes clear that each file name should be on its own line:

```
::
:: Exclude These Files :
::
        /XF             :: eXclude Files matching these names
                *.exe
                *.img
```

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. :)